# How to show the similar dropdown menu for separate div elements within one page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-core

I'm a novice in asp.net and programming at whole (also this is my first question so don't judge harshly).

I have a problem with my first project. On my page there are several tiles which are of the same style. On each tile I'd like to add a dropdown menu with CRUD options (View, Update, Delete). I have found a solution but it appears that no matter on what tile I click the menu button, dropdown menu shows always on the first one.
I want to show menu on the tile on which I have clicked the menu button to apply actions only to a selected element.

**My HTML:**

```
<div class="tile-menu-dropdown">
    <button onclick="tileMenu()" class="tile-menu-btn">
        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v fa-2x" style="pointer-events: none;"></i>
    </button>
    <div id="tile-menu" class="tile-menu-content">
        <button>View</button>
        <button>Edit</button>
        <button>Delete</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**My CSS:**

```
.tiles .tile .tile-menu-btn {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            text-align: right;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            padding-top: 14px;
            padding-right: 14px;
            background: none;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            font-size: 16px;
            color: #ffffff;
            transition: 0.3s;
            transition-property: color;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

            .tiles .tile .tile-menu-btn:hover {
                color: #cd42e9;
            }

.tile-menu-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background: #2F323A;
    min-width: 80px;
    border: 2px solid #cd42e9;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 5px;
    right: 0;
    top: 50px;
}

    .tile-menu-content button {
        background: none;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        width: 100%;
        color: #ffffff;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: left;
        font-size: 17px;
        font-weight: 500;
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        display: block;
    }

        .tile-menu-content button:hover {
            color: #cd42e9;
            background: #22242A;
        }

.show {
    display: block;
}
```

**My JavaScript:**

```
function tileMenu() {
    document.getElementById("tile-menu").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.tile-menu-btn')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("tile-menu-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `Id` to get the element, if there are many elements with the same Id, it will always triget the first one.

So you can locate the target element start from the element currently triggering the event.

```
<div class="tile-menu-dropdown">
    <button onclick="tileMenu(this)" class="tile-menu-btn">
        menu1
    </button>
    <div id="tile-menu" class="tile-menu-content">
        <button>View</button>
        <button>Edit</button>
        <button>Delete</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tile-menu-dropdown">
    <button onclick="tileMenu(this)" class="tile-menu-btn">
        menu2
    </button>
    <div id="tile-menu" class="tile-menu-content">
        <button>View2</button>
        <button>Edit2</button>
        <button>Delete2</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
    function tileMenu(element) {
        clearMenuStatus();
        element.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
    }

    window.onclick = function (event) {
        if (!event.target.matches('.tile-menu-btn')) {
            clearMenuStatus();
        }
    }

    function clearMenuStatus() {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("tile-menu-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Result:

[image]